# Error when creating Zip files in Mono using System.IO.Compression

Tags: .net, mono, .net-4.5

I'm porting a small console app (.NET 4.5) to Mono (3.4.0 running on OpenSUSE 13.1). It seems that some methods under `System.IO.Compression` and `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` are not implemented?

If I don't include these two DLLs with my exe, I will get

> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NotImplementedException: The
>   requested feature is not implemented.

If I include those two DLLs, I will get

> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidProgramException:
>   Invalid IL code in System.IO.Compression.ZipFile:CreateFromDirectory
>   (string,string,System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel,bool): method
>   body is empty.

There doesn't seem to be too much information regarding these namespaces at http://www.go-mono.com/status/.

Has anyone used the .NET 4.5 built-in functions to create and extract Zip files in Mono? Did I miss somethng or should I use a 3rd-party library like `SharpZipLib`?

Comment: Well, that is tough cookies then, complain to Xamarin to implement those methods.

Comment: BTW, IIRC, `Ionic.Zip` (or something like that) work on Mono with a small patch (see the project issues page). Used it a few years back.

Comment: Awesome. I think I'll switch back to Ionic.Zip (switched to the built-in one when .NET 4.5 came out). Thanks!

Comment: Mono itself already uses sharpziplib though. That should make it easy to implement the missing functionality, if anybody cared enough.

Comment: Next time please simply go to GitHub and check out the corresponding source files, such as https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.IO.Compression.FileSystem/ZipFile.cs. When something is not implemented, find an alternative way, and usually you can.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up replacing the `System.IO.Compression` calls with `SharpZipLib.FastZip`. It was extremely easy and only involved getting the binary from NuGet, replacing the built-in function calls with SharpZipLib's, and running on Mono.

Thanks to @leppie and @Jester for the comments!